# Generic constructor template called instead of copy/move constructor

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, constructor-overloading

I've designed a simpler wrapper class that adds a label to an object, with the intent of being implicitly convertible/able to replace the wrapped object.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template < typename T, typename Key = std::string >
class myTag{
    T val;
 public:
    Key key;

    template < typename... Args,
               typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_constructible< T, Args... >::value >::type >
    myTag(Args&&... args) :
        val(std::forward< Args >(args)...) {
            std::cout << "forward ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    myTag(const myTag& other) :
        key(other.key), val(other.val) {
            std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    myTag(myTag&& other):
        key(other.key), val(other.val) {
            std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    operator T&() { return val; }

    operator const T&() const { return val; }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    myTag< float > foo(5.6);   // forward ctor
    myTag< float > bar(foo);   // forward ctor

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am having trouble properly declaring & defining the copy/move constructor. I declared a generic constructor overload template that forwards its arguments to the underlying type, *as long as such construction is possible*. However, due to the implicit conversion operators, it is capturing every instantiation of `myTag`, effectively shadowing the copy/move constructors.

The point of non-default copy/move semantics was to copy/move the *key* value vs default-initializing it with constructor template.

How do I make the compiler prefer/give precedence to the explicit copy/move constructors vs the generic overload? Is there any additional SFINAE check alternative to `is_constructible<>` that avoids implicit conversions?

EDIT: I should add that I'm looking for a C++14 solution.

Comment: It's going to take a better language lawyer than me ( recommend you add that tag ) to tell you WHY, but you can fix it by adding a `myTag(myTag& other)` overload as well.  The problem is that foo is not a `myTag&&`, and it's not a `const myTag&`, so ithe compiler is choosing to convert via the `operator T&` conversion and use the first constructor.

Comment: You can also extend the `enable_if` to disallow this overload if there is exactly 1 argument, and that argument is a `myTag` (removing cv and references from the type).

Comment: @DaveS yes that works. I just don't understad why `foo` is not a `const myTag&`, or rather, why it `const myTag&` does not bind to it instead of the compiler looking for alternative overloads.

Comment: @joaocandre: I think the point you're confused by is the fact that a `myTag&` is not bound to a `const myTag&` during overload selection.  During overload selection, it's looking for exact matches first, and the matches that require some sort of conversion (e.g `myTag&` to `const myTag&`).  So, since your forwarding constructor doesn't require conversion, it will get selected unless one of the other overloads is an exact match.

Comment: @DaveS but that's precisely my point - the forward constructor *should* require conversion, because `float` is not constructible from any variation of `myTag` arguments - as far as I know it is calling the implicit conversion overload `operator T&` and copying into the new instance. The SFINAE check should (ideally) fail for `myTag&`, `const myTag&` or similar, and thus the copy/move constructors should be called.

Comment: @joaocandre During template expansion, Args is set to `myTag&`, with the potential definition of `myTag(myTag&)`.  Given that, `std::is_constructible<float, myTag&>::value` will be true (due to the conversion operator).  Therefore, the template is valid.  Now you have a (templated) constructor which exactly matches the actual input parameters, while the other two require conversion.  Overload selection picks that constructor, passing it the actual parameter `myTag&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't shadowing the copy and move constructors. It is just beating them in overload resolution in some cases.

- If you pass a `myTag<float>&`, the forwarding constructor is used.
- If you pass a `const myTag<float>&` the copy constructor is used.
- If you pass a `myTag<float>&&`, the move constructor is used.
- If you pass a `const myTag<float>&&`, the forwarding constructor is used.

The copy and move constructors are not templates, so they will win against a template of the same signature. But the forwarding constructor can be a better match in the cases where the deduced signature differs from the copy and move constructors.

The idiomatic way to handle this is to remove the forwarding constructor from consideration based on the decayed type of the arguments:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr myTag(Args&&... args)
    requires
        ((sizeof...(Args) != 1 && std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>) ||
         (sizeof...(Args) == 1 && std::is_convertible_v<Args..., T> && !std::is_same_v<myTag, std::decay_t<Args>...>))
```

Comment: Thanks. There must obviously be reasons for it - but I do think it is weird that overload resolution would rather perform an implicit conversion to `T` than bind a `myTag&` to `const myTag&`

Comment: Also, I should add that I'm looking for a C++14 solution.

Comment: It's not that it prefers the implicit conversion. It's that, because the convertibility constraint is satisfied, that constructor is available (not SFINAE'd away). That constructor deduces an argument which is a very good match (`myTag&`). So overload resolution is choosing to bind the `myTag&` argument to `myTag&` instead of `const myTag&`. The problem is that forwarding references are, by design, usually a very good match. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: (For C++14, just take the boolean expression and put it in the enable_if instead of in a requires clause.)